# Parse Compelete Web Page

Tags: c#, parsing, html-agility-pack

How to parse complete HTML web page not specific nodes using HTML Agility Pack or any other technique?

I am using this code, but this code only parse specific node, but I need complete page to parse with neat and clear contents

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
string url = "https://www.google.com";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a"))
{
   list.Add(node.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your requirements.  Is it that you refuse to use a library such as HTML agility pack or that the library doesn't suit your needs? If the latter, in what way?  What do you mean by "this code only parse specific node" and "I need complete page to parse" and "with neat and clear contents".  I don't understand what you mean by any of those phrases.

Comment: I also am unsure what you mean by "complete page to parse ".    If you do  `SelectNodes("*")` you will get all the nodes in the page.

Comment: See the above code extracts the inner text of all tag <a> that exists in a web page, i simply want to extracts inner text for all tags like <p>, <span>,<a>,<image>,<h1>, etc from a web page.

Comment: I'll copy my comment to be an answer because I think that is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all descendant text nodes use something like

```
var textNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()").
                                 Select(t=>t.InnerText);
```

To get all non empty descendant text nodes

```
var textNodes = doc.DocumentNode.
                    SelectNodes("//text()[normalize-space()]").
                    Select(t=>t.InnerText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do `SelectNodes("*")` .   '*' (asterisk) Is the wild card selector and will get every node on the page.